# I cannot figure out how to spread out the space on the y axis for my scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I entered this code with the `x`, `y`, and `size` defined by variables I created earlier. The problem is that the points are too bunched up and I want to stretch out my y-axis.

```
plt.scatter(rets.mean(),rets.std(),s = area)
plt.xlabel('Expected Return')
plt.ylabel('Risk')
```

For example, right now my y-axis goes from `-0.005` to `0.04` in increments of `0.005`, how would I adjust it to count in increments of `0.0025`?

Comment: @TrisNefzger This is really heavy handed and not the best approach.

Comment: @tcaswell - Is that documented and where? Using yticks is shown in examples such as http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/psd_demo3.html  and there is no warning about using it in http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html.

Comment: The reason it is a bad idea is that it sets your ticks to only _ever_ be at the points you list.  If you pan at all you will loose your ticks.  The docs have gotten (well) behind the code.  Any help would be welcome.

Comment: @tcaswell: Ok I understand your point. However most of the time I do exploratory analysis for which quick and dirty is best. For example, plt.xticks(np.arange(101),tuple(list(a))) where a = '12345678911234567892...' was easy to do and worked fine to find peak # of friends on a histogram. I don't need the ticker module for this and on inspection found that its relatively heavy with more than a few classes and is about 2/3 the size of pyplot which is all I really need for plotting most of the time. I can see ticker being useful when creating more complex and professional quality plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticks

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_ylim((-.005, .04))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticks.MultipleLocator(.0025))
```

[image]